# Bounce processing - will fail for G Suite users when Google disables less secure apps in Feb 2021

Tags: civimail, scheduled-job

Google have announced they are [stopping support of less secure apps in G Suite](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/12/less-secure-apps-oauth-google-username-password-incorrect.html) in Feb 2021. No new LSA connections will be allowed after Jun 2020.

Google have advised me that the email accounts I'm using for Bounce Processing and Email-to-Activity Processing are affected by this.

Google's advice is "For any other LSA, contact your admin or ask the developer of the app you are using to start supporting OAuth".

Are there any plans for CiviCRM to support connecting to IMAP or POP using OAuth authentication?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers to the Issue and the PR. I'll take a look! My previous post covered the sending of emails and I didn't even consider bounce processing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a potential workaround for anyone who can set up a non-G-Suite IMAP account. I haven't implemented or tested this.

1. Continue using your G Suite email address - it has your domain name and Google does SPAM etc processing
2. Forward email to your non-G-Suite account
3. Use this second account for Bounce Processing

Comment: Ken - do you still recommend this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a potential workaround for anyone who can set up a Maildir on their server and run jobs. I haven't implemented or tested this.

1. Continue using your G Suite email address - it has your domain name
   and Google does SPAM etc processing
2. Find an app for your server that can read an IMAP account, uses OAuth for authentication, and populates a Maildir
3. Run the job regularly
4. Use the Maildir for Bounce Processing

Comment: Ken - do you still recommend this approach?